# custom remote validator with client_side_validations

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, ruby-on-rails-3.2, client-side-validation

I am trying to build custom remote validator using client_side_validations based on this [tutorial](https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations/wiki/Custom-Validators).
So far I have this:

config/initializers/custom_validators.rb

```
class JobsOverlapValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attr_name, value)
   #validation code
  end
end

# This allows us to assign the validator in the model
module ActiveModel::Validations::HelperMethods
  def validates_jobs_overlap(*attr_names)
    validates_with JobsOverlapValidator, _merge_attributes(attr_names)
  end
end
```

app/models/job.rb

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  validates_jobs_overlap :starts_at
  ...
end
```

app/middleware/client_side_validations/jobs_overlap.rb

```
module ClientSideValidations
  module Middleware
    class JobsOverlap < Base
      def response
         ....
         if true
          self.status = 200
        else
          self.status = 404
        end
        super
      end
    end
  end
end
```

app/assets/javascripts/rails.validations.custom.js

```
ClientSideValidations.validators.remote['jobs_overlap'] = function(element, options) {
  if ($.ajax({
    url: '/validators/jobs_overlap',
    data: { id: element.val() },
    // async *must* be false
    async: false
  }).status == 404) { return options.message; }
}
```

app/assets/javascript/application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery_nested_form
//= require application/rails.validations
//= require application/rails.validations.nested_form
//= require application/rails.validations.custom
...
```

I believe problem is that my custom validation is not contained in script generated by client_side_validations:

```
//<![CDATA[
if(window.ClientSideValidations===undefined)window.ClientSideValidations={};window.ClientSideValidations.disabled_validators=[];window.ClientSideValidations.number_format={"separator":".","delimiter":","};if(window.ClientSideValidations.patterns===undefined)window.ClientSideValidations.patterns = {};window.ClientSideValidations.patterns.numericality=/^(-|\+)?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:\,\d{3})+)(?:\.\d*)?$/;if(window.ClientSideValidations.remote_validators_prefix===undefined)window.ClientSideValidations.remote_validators_prefix='';if(window.ClientSideValidations.forms===undefined)window.ClientSideValidations.forms={};window.ClientSideValidations.forms['jobs_modal_form'] = {"type":"ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder","input_tag":"<div class='control-group error'><span id=\"input_tag\" ></span><span class=\"help-inline\"></span></div>","label_tag":"<div class='control-group error'><label id=\"label_tag\" ></label><span class=\"help-inline\"></span></div>","validators":{"job[client_attributes][name]":{"presence":[{"message":"can't be blank"}],"length":[{"messages":{"maximum":"is too long (maximum is 50 characters)"},"maximum":50}]},"job[client_attributes][contact_name]":{"length":[{"messages":{"maximum":"is too long (maximum is 50 characters)"},"maximum":50}]},"job[client_attributes][contact_phone]":{"length":[{"messages":{"maximum":"is too long (maximum is 50 characters)"},"maximum":50}]},"job[client_attributes][contact_email]":{"format":[{"message":"is invalid","with":/^([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})$/i,"allow_blank":true}],"length":[{"messages":{"maximum":"is too long (maximum is 50 characters)"},"maximum":50}]},"job[client_attributes][address]":{"length":[{"messages":{"maximum":"is too long (maximum is 100 characters)"},"maximum":100}]},"job[description]":{"presence":[{"message":"can't be blank"}],"length":[{"messages":{"maximum":"is too long (maximum is 500 characters)"},"maximum":500}]}}};
//]]>
```

Does anyone ever encountered similar issue? Why client_side_validations doesn't create my validations same way others are created on client?
Thanks for any help, I am stuck on this issue and have no idea how to continue :).